# Make a echo statement to vanish after 2 seconds

Tags: php

I have a form ,if a user submits data, he will get a message like data successfully submitted.
I want this message to vanish after 2 seconds.

I used this function set_time_limit(2); but this is not working.

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This needs to be done on the client side, not on the server, which is where you are going wrong. You need to put some JavaScript on the webpage that will hide the message, like so:

```
function hideMessage() {
    document.getElementById("message_div").style.display = "none";
};
setTimeout(hideMessage, 2000);
```

Comment: I am displaying it in the client side only.You can see the above snippet that is how i am using.

Comment: @user554176 There's no `set_time_limit` function on the client-side. That's a PHP function, and PHP is exclusively server-side.

Comment: @user55423423, The code to that you are writing runs on the __server__ and emits (presumably) *HTML*. HTML is not a _programming language_ and does not allow for *dynamic content* which is what something that disappears after two seconds is. That code has to run on the *client* and the only language that does that universally is Javascript.

Comment: @user554176 No, you have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

`set_time_limit(2)` just means your script will die if it takes more than two seconds to process.

This is generally done with a little JavaScript (using the `setTimeout` function). PHP has little involvement.

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but the function name for delayed action is setTimeout, not getTimeout.

Comment: Whoops, yep, that's a timeout. Thanks, fixing.

Answer (score 1):

add id on message :

```
 echo "<p id='connectMsg' class='alert alert-success'>Connected successfully to the database.</p>";
```

and after add that javascript code on your script section

```
    document.getElementById("connectMsg").style.display = "none"
};
setTimeout(hideMessage,2000);
```